# Resolving the too many redirects on wordpress

Tags: redirect, htaccess, seo

I'm trying to solve a problem on my wordpress that I'm seeing both on Semrush and Google webmaster

My issue

It's considering a 3 times redirect on a link (that I'm not finding on the database)

https://blog.com
https://www.blog.com
https://www.blog.com/

I remove the slash from the permanent link
I deactivated the w3 cache tool
I review the htaccess
I review the wp-config

I don't know where else to look now to try to get rid of the last redirect or the first, any tips will be more than helpful

Answer (score 0):

Other places to check:

- If you're on an Nginx server, check the server config
- Deactivate all plugins and switch to a default theme
- If you use a host with a control panel, check there for hidden redirects

Each time you make a change, use an Incognito window or a header check tool to verify - your browser caches redirects so it may be fixed even when your browser is taking you through the old redirects.